# WindowsFormsWebBrowser drag drop functionality

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows forms webbrowser 
(Windows.Forms.WebBrowser)  I want to capture the drag drop event over it.

I did not see any drag drop events on it that I can hook into ? It just has DoDragDrop()

Could you please guide me as to how to capture the drag drop event on it? I want to handle these events in a parent control that hosts it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Drag Drop on the WebBrowser control via the "AllowWebBrowserDrop" property, i.e.

```
webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = true;
```

Then you can intercept the "Navigating" event to read the URL that was dropped:

```
  private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
  {
     MessageBox.Show(e.Url.ToString());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron, but how do I hook up the drag over event equivalent for the browser control? the navigating gets run AFTER you drop the files right? I want an event that gets fired when it is over the control...Thanks!

Comment: This property is set to "true" by default. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.allowwebbrowserdrop(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To cancel the navigation event, do this:

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

This should do the trick.